# jQuery/JavaScript Code Only Displays When I log directly into console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

This is a pretty vague question so let me know if this needs to be further clarified. When I log some jQuery code directly into the console, the code seems to execute, but I have no luck, when I inserted into my JS file. It's pretty basic code:

```
$('.photo-list').on('click', function (event) {
console.log("HELLO!");
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what else do you expect this code to do besides log to the console?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: My guess with this limited information is that this jquery is binding the event to an element that does not exist yet. Try moving jquery code to the end of your html document. See if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind to the click event of that element, that element has to exist within the DOM before your code runs. You might want to wrap your code within a document ready block. Also make sure that you include your js file in the html.

```
$(function(){
//your code
});
```